# I want fetch 10 notification form each notification type in Django or sql

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a `Notification` table where multiple fields are there also it contain `notification_type` fields.

Currently i'm using query like this to get 10 records for each notification type.
But here i'm calling multiple query.

```
notify_type = Notify.objects.filter(user__id=1).values_list('type', flat=True).distinct()
for n_type in notify_type:
      return Notification.objects.filter(user__id=1, type=n_type).order_by('-id')[:10]
```

I want to use only one SQL query or ORM to fetch data.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Notification.objects.filter(user__id=1, type__in=notify_type).order_by('-id')?

Comment: is `type` a foreign key or a regular value like CharField or IntegerField?

Comment: `type` is text field

Comment: `Notification.objects.filter(user__id=1, type__in=notify_type).order_by('-id')[100]`  this will give us last 100 records, where type_a can have any values, type_a should have only 10 values